# Prove that $\gcd(\operatorname{lcm} (a,b),c) = \operatorname{lcm}(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,c))$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Help me please I'm stuck in this problem. Prove that $$\gcd(\operatorname{lcm} (a,b),c) = \operatorname{lcm}(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,c)).$$

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is checking prime exponents. Let $v_p(x)$ be the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $x$. Obviously if $v_p(x)=v_p(y)$ for all $p$, then $x=y$. We can also check that $v_p(lcm(x,y))=max(v_p(x),v_p(y))$, and $v_p(gcd(x,y))=min(v_p(x),v_p(y))$.

So your statement is equivalent to:

$$min(max(v_p(a),v_p(b)),v_p(c))=max(min(v_p(a),v_p(c),min(v_p(b),v_p(c))$$

You can check this via casework on the order of $v_p(a),v_p(b),v_p(c)$.